# Передача ссылочного параметра в метод по значению

Tags: c#

В документации microsoft написано, что если передавать ссылочный тип по значению, то фактически в метод передаётся копия на ссылку. Тогда почему если в методе изменить этот параметр, то потом вернувшись в main значение остаётся изменённым? Если бы передавалась сама ссылка а не её копия тогда было бы понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно рассмотреть такой пример

```
class MyClass
{
    // инициализируем поле 20.
    public int Val = 20;
}

class Program
{
    static void MyMethod(MyClass f1, int f2)
    {
        // Увеличиваем на 5 значение поля у ссылочного типа
        f1.Val = f1.Val + 5;
        // Увеличиваем на 5 значение у значимого типа
        f2 = f2 + 5; 

        Console.WriteLine($"Окончание метода MyMethod(): f1.Val=={f1.Val}, f2=={f2}");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //создаем ссылочный тип
        MyClass a1 = new MyClass();
        //создаем значимый тип
        int a2 = 10;

        Console.WriteLine($"До вызова метода MyMethod(): a1.Val=={a1.Val}, a2=={a2}");

        //вызоваем метод
        MyMethod(a1, a2);

        Console.WriteLine($"После отработки метода MyMethod(): a1.Val=={a1.Val}, a2=={a2}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Результат работы такой
[image: вывод примера на консоль]

Что происходит при этом в `Стеке` и `Куче` поможет понять такая иллюстрация
[image: иллюстрация работы стека и кучи]

Пример и иллюстрация взяты из книги [Illustrated C# 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484232879)

P.S. для случая передачи параметров по ссылке изменим в предыдущем примере метод так

```
static void MyMethod(ref MyClass f1, ref int f2)
```

и его вызов так

```
MyMethod(ref a1, ref a2);
```

Вывод будет таким
[image: вывод в консоль для др.примера]
Иллюстрация к происходящему
[image: иллюстрация работы примера в случае передачи параметров по ссылке]

Теперь изменим пример так

```
class Program
{
    static void MyMethod(MyClass f1)
    {
        f1.Val = 50;
        Console.WriteLine($"После изменения значения в MyMethod(): { f1.Val }");

        //здесь мы изменяем ссылку на др. экземпляр класса
        f1 = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine($"После присвоения нового экземпляра класса в MyMethod(): {f1.Val}");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass a1 = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine($"До вызова метода MyMethod():{a1.Val}");

        MyMethod(a1);
        Console.WriteLine($"После отработки метода MyMethod(): {a1.Val}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Результат работы такой
[image: результат работы 3-его примера]
Иллюстрация происходящего
[image: иллюстрация 3-го примера]

Теперь снова изменим метод

```
static void MyMethod(ref MyClass f1)
```

и его вызов

```
MyMethod(ref a1);
```

Результат работы такой
[image: результат работы 4-го примера]
Иллюстрация к присходящему
[image: иллюстрация работы стека и кучи для 4-го примера]
Тут уж все возможные случаи продемонстрированы.